# Why is it "I saw you kiss her yesterday" instead of "I saw you kissed her yesterday"?

Tags: tense-agreement

I have seen in a movie a strange sentence which is:

> I saw you kiss her yesterday.

So considering that is past simple, she should have said 'kissed' instead of 'kiss'.

I don't understand why we don't say :

> I saw you kissed her yesterday.

Comment: We *do* say 'I saw you kissed her yesterday'; we also say the first one. They have different sentence structures.

Answer (score 3):

You are encountering a situation known as a "verb of perception" - *kiss* here is an infinitive, but it's in one of the situations where *to* is not used before it.

Read [this](http://www.englishgrammar.org/hear-object-infinitive/).

Excerpt from the  above:

> Most verbs of perception (e.g. hear, see, watch, notice) are followed
>   by object + infinitive (without to).
>
> - I heard him cry. (NOT I heard him to cry.)
> - I watched them play. (NOT I watched them to play.)
> - I saw her cross the road. (NOT I saw her to cross the road.)
>
> Most of these verbs can also be followed by –ing forms.
>
> Note that there is usually a difference of meaning.
>
> We use infinitive forms after these verbs to say that we hear or see
>   the whole of an action or event. On the other hand, -ing forms suggest
>   that we see or hear an action in progress.

Comment: In addition, the sentence 'I saw (that) you kissed her yesterday' is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

He is saying that he actually saw him kiss her. It was present tense at the time he was seeing them - the past tense is in the word "saw".

If you wanted to use "kissed", you'd have to say something like

> I saw that you kissed her.

But that means something subtly different. You'd say that if you saw the results of the kiss, not the kiss itself - perhaps some lipstick on his lips?